# ThreeJS Orbit object around (0,0,0)

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

[image: 1]

I have created a ThreeJS Scene as in the image.
And I have created 2 methods to rotate the `Obj2` around the `Obj1` in required `distance`.

```
function configureObj2PositionHorizontally(angleInDegree) {
  radianAngle = angleInDegree * oneDegreeInRadians;

  obj2Mesh.position.x = distance * Math.cos(radianAngle);
  obj2Mesh.position.z = distance * Math.sin(radianAngle);

  console.log(radianAngle, distance);
}

function configureObj2PositionVertically(angleInDegree) {
  radianAngle = angleInDegree * oneDegreeInRadians;

  obj2Mesh.position.y = distance * Math.sin(radianAngle);
  obj2Mesh.position.z = distance * Math.cos(radianAngle);

  console.log(radianAngle, distance);
}
```

Issue is if the object comes to a point like `pointA` and I try to rotate vertically it is rotating around the `Z` axis. Not around the center point (0,0,0).
But I need the `Obj2` to rotate/orbit only around the `Obj1` ( its placed on (0,0,0)) not around the axis.

How to fix this behaviour?

You can find the JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/janithsg/y8upn26v/25/

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to create a group, with the same position of Obj1, add Obj2 to this group, and rotate the group around its Y and X axis (if Obj2 is initially displaced along Z axis).

This code do the work:

```
const obj1Mesh = new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.5), 
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xffff00 })
)
scene.add(obj1Mesh)

const obj2Mesh = new THREE.Mesh(
  new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.2), 
  new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x909090 })
)
obj2Mesh.position.z = - distance
scene.add(obj2Mesh)

const obj2Group = new THREE.Group()
obj2Group.add(obj2Mesh)
scene.add(obj2Group)

function configureObj2PositionHorizontally(angleInDegree: number) {
  const radianAngle = angleInDegree * oneDegreeInRadians;

  obj2Group.rotateY(radianAngle)
}

function configureObj2PositionVertically(angleInDegree: number) {
  const radianAngle = angleInDegree * oneDegreeInRadians;

  obj2Group.rotateX(radianAngle)
}
```

If you then want to move Obj1, with Obj2 still orbiting around it, you can create another group that comprises both obj1Mesh and obj2Group, and move this new group:

```
const mainGroup = new THREE.Group()
mainGroup.add(obj1Mesh, obj2Group)
mainGroup.translateX(2)
scene.add(mainGroup)
```